# "Keep me motivated" or "keep myself motivated"?

Tags: grammar

Which statement is more correct?

> I am doing this to keep me motivated.

OR

> I am doing this to keep myself motivated.

Answer (score 5):

If the object of the verb is the same as the subject of the verb, you need to use a *reflexive pronoun*. So it needs to be:

> I am doing this to keep *myself* motivated.

Similarly:

> He cut *himself* while shaving.
>
> The cat hurt *itself* when it fell from the tree.
>
> You are only deceiving *yourselves*.

You use the *personal pronoun* as the object when the subject is someone different:

> He is doing this to keep *me* motivated.

Comment: For some reason, I don't have a problem with “I'm doing this to keep me motivated”. In all the other persons, I'd never say it with a simple pronoun, either, but with ‘me’ specifically, it doesn't jar on my ears. I wonder why this is…

Comment: The to- (= in order to ...) string distances the objective pronoun from the subject pronoun, so perhaps it sounds acceptable because it reflects “He's doing this to keep me motivated”. But “He's doing this to keep him motivated” implies two different (third) persons.

Comment: @Janus, You can certainly find similar examples in the wild. Here's one: http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/jordan-cieciwa/exercise-social-media_b_4869913.html. Edwin's theory about its acceptability sounds feasible to me. But I wouldn't recommend the usage to an English language learner.

Comment: @Edwin, for the third person, it makes sense. But why does it jar just as badly if I say, “You're doing it to keep you motivated” or “We're doing it to keep us motivated” (which has even less possibility of representing different subject and object)? The pronouns are just as far separated as with ‘me’, but only ‘me’ doesn't jar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Probably it doesn't jar because people tend to use it, so it is a familiar sound.

Comment: @WS2, well, yes. That's what dictates what jars and does not; but why is one used and the other not? That was what I can't think of any logical answer to, even though it seems like such a structural and non-idiomatic aspect of syntax and morphology that there ought to be a systematic justification of some kind to it.

Comment: @Janus Just sit in front of your strong computer and have a powerful cup of tea.